# .Net 4.0 Windows Application crashes in clr.dll under Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, .net-4.0, crash, clr

I have a Windows application scheduled to run on a daily basis and fails intermittently as per the following log in EventViewer.

```
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4d54829a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba21eeb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000029e1
Faulting process id: 0xbb1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cbd99223d8b4eb
Faulting application path: E:\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 7e74ec7e-45a5-11e0-a95d-003048de380d
```

And in the second EventViewer log it says:

```
The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF97329E1 (000007FEF9730000) with exit code 80131506.
```

The server is Win Server 2008 R2 and the application uses .Net 4.0 (as you can see in the error log too).

The application uses multi-threading intensively and reads from a remote database and writes to local hard disk.

Any guesses on what causes this issue and any suggestions on how to investigate? I have no idea where it fails in the life of the application which is about 5-10 hours.

Comment: "Fatal Execution Engine Error", the garbage collected heap got corrupted.  Good luck.

Comment: contact Microsoft Support and give them a crash dump of your process...

Comment: You using COM components or anything else you should be telling us about? Have you searched around for the various codes in your message to see if anyone else has already posted similar things?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. At approximately 8-10 hours of application life CLR error rises. I suspected my unmanaged code generating exception in the background thread. However I could not really find out why. You can give the following a try however:

- If you are using unmanaged code review exception handling statements
  while executig it.
- Make sure you have the latest fixes of .NET4.
  (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads)

Please let me know if you have already found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Actually, not on purpose to solve this problem, but just to improve the performance of the application we replaced the hard disk by a very fast one and all these weird things have gone away, the application runs so quickly now with no issue. Previously the application would use too much of resources (mainly memory) because it would allow one thread at a time to write to disk and all data would accumulate in memory; which could be a cause for this issue. Windows operating systems are not famous in handling such tough cases properly, are they? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so this can help future user to find a solution :

We use Apache log4net for application log.

After an update to DLL version 1.2.15, for dotnet Framwork 4.5 it starts to fire this exact exception once the log file reach the maximal size (10MB)

Answer (score 1):

The hot-fix has mostly vanished and I faced a similar issue, so I'll share my answer here.

My solution revolved around the fact that I was passing a Lamda to a P/Invoke:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360307/4700841