# The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime with exit code 80131506

Tags: .net, windows-services

We had a windows service running .NET 2.0 for a long time and we upgraded it to .NET 4.0 two months back. For few days it was fine, then the service started crashing (.NET runtime itself crashes) with the following entry in the event log. I came across this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime) and now got stuck. This service doesn't use any COM Interop, but it does use a third party library (Aspose PDF). Any help will be much appreciated.

> The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 791F7DB6 (79140000) with exit code 80131506.

Comment: FEEE, Fatal Execution Engine Error.  Early versions of the CLR could cause it, that's been long solved.  You can safely assume that your 3rd party library is frumping the heap.  Get another one, they won't fix it for you.

Comment: I suddenly started getting these a few months ago. Replaced the memory in my laptop - no more errors. Sometimes it's the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

First off, please try to use the Aspose.Pdf DLL built for .NET 4.0. You can find it in the Aspose.Pdf for .NET installation directory. You can also try the latest version of [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx). Also, please try to get the log and other related details to find out whether it is caused by Aspose.Pdf or not. If it is the component and you get the same exception with latest version and 4.0 build then please post a query in [Aspose.Pdf forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx) at Aspose website along with the sample project etc., so our team would be able to investigate and resolve this issue for you. Moreover, this component doesn't use any unmanaged code and there is no COM interop involved with it either.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Shahzad. Will check this and post my comments.

Answer (score -1):

wrap a try and cacth around the main execution and use log4net to log any errors. Set it to email them to you. Then throw them again. this should hopefully allow you to see the actual error.

Comment: exceptions that are this serve wont get catch by try catch block. .NET runtime will immediately crash it