# .NET 4 Runtime Internal Error

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application Crashes With “Internal Error In The .NET Runtime”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime)

We have a complex C# (.NET 4) Windows Service that runs 24x7. It's not unusual for the Windows service to throw an exception (such as when a database call times out). We catch all these exceptions properly using try/catch blocks. It should not be possible for an unhandled exception to bring our service down.

Every once in a while, usually when a SQL Server 2008 database call times out, our try/catch code will handle it properly, but the service will get shut down with the following error written to the Event Log:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET 
    Runtime at IP 6F637CB5 (6F590000) with exit code 80131506.
```

Does anyone have any idea what causes this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Crashes With "Internal Error In The .NET Runtime"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime), also have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/194623/how-to-resolve-internal-errors-in-the-net-runtime

Comment: Specifically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4367865/635634) answer to the question Tim referenced seems applicable.