# xxx.exe has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m and needs to close

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting programs from VB6 to VB.NET with VS2005 then to VS2010 .

This error had occured:

> 'xxx.exe' has encountered a problem and needs to close.

while I was running a report function in an application and caused it to terminate. I read message from event view.

It said the source was

> .NET Runtime 4.0 Error Reporting, event ID: 1000
>    desc:Faulting application tpatoprt.exe, version 2.0.4574.21092, stamp 4ffbaa28, faulting module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.269, stamp 4ee9ae83, debug? 0, fault address 0x0019b930.

and

> .NET Runtime, event ID :1023 
>    desc:
>   Application: TPATOPrt.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 792DB930 (79140000) with exit code 80131506.

The following link just like my problem: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_681goxWLnCg/S99AQRndqII/AAAAAAAAAfA/KQBnplFJ5-Y/fake_svchost_popup.jpg

I tried to correct in many ways..but sadly it still occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Crashes With "Internal Error In The .NET Runtime"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime)

Comment: thanks for ur opinions, but how can i solve it ?

Comment: Poss OT but I believe that the migration wizard to vb2008 works better than the one to vb2005 (maybe partly due to differences between vb2005 and vb2008)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to assume that the problem is to do with your code, unless you find otherwise. Hans Passant helpfully gave you a link to a similar issue. You might have noticed that nobody was able to give a solution, even though this was two years ago. As a result, you are unlikely to get a direct solution, unless you are lucky enough to have an expert at .NET runtime looking at your question.

You best bet is for you to try and work out the source of the problem yourself. Do you get any kind of callstack? If so, then that would be a great clue as to the line on which error occurred. Otherwise, step through the code in the debugger until you find the line which causes the error. At this point, you might be able to fix the problem yourself. But in any case, post the lines of code which cause this problem, and you might get a bigger response.

Comment: thank you so much , i tried use try catch but is not work since the error occur only without debug mode. let me try callstack.

Comment: i found the error is from my code and starting debug it thank you

Comment: Can you please answer yourself with your solution? It looks so sad when there is no green tick on a question :-)

Comment: sure=] \n nice to sharing my exp for all =]

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this problem,
I use try..catch or On Error GoTo ErrExit for finding which part of code make the error of
'xxx.exe' has encountered a problem and needs to close. occur.
then rewrite the code since there have one or more code make it happen.
try to use other way to replace older code.
then run again, it successes.
all error disappear.

I hope this may help others to solve the problem.