# wpf application crashes when accessed from RDP session without showing any ERROR messages

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have been working on this issue from the past 7 days but could not figure out the actual reason. I have created an MSI for WPF application and installed it in windows 7 machine. IF i physically log into that machine and access the application everything works fine.

But when I access the application using Remote Desktop Session, the application crashes without showing me any error. I checked in the application logs in event viewer and found the following Errors

**1. .Net RunTime Error:**

**Application : Myapplication.exe**

**Framework Version: v4.0.30319**

**Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP732E1F88 (732B0000) with exit code 80131506**

**2. Application Error :**

Description:
Faulting application name: , version: , time stamp: 0x4e11b8da

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc

Faulting process id: 0xd44

Faulting application start time: 0x01ce40fa0f61d32c

Faulting application path:

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id:

Could someone please help me out where I am going wrong or do i need to change any settings

Thanks

Comment: This bug report may be relevant:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1930838/animated-wpf-effects-cause-hard-crash-over-rdp-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Did you read: [WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler) so you can get more info about the exception?

Put something like this in your App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    base.OnStartup(e);
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: {0} ", e.ExceptionObject));
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed the internal error in the .NET Runtime maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime this can help

Comment: I have added all the exceptions as mentioned in this page [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Handling-Unhandled-47492d0b#content) but could not see any exceptions. Finally I figured out it was an issue with scroll viewer styling but could not pinpoint the exact line which is causing this issue. Thanks for your  help on this.