# The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Im using a WPF and somehow today i got this new crash info:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 6AD0B1AC (6A9B0000) with exit code e0004743.
```

I have no idea what this is. I've tried to google it but i couldn't find anything related to this exit code.

Comment: You should give us more informations...

Comment: Well i dont have more information to give. The app was idle by the time it crashed, then this is what event viewer gives to me.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: Are you using an x64 .NET 4.0 application? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2679415

Comment: Open Event Viewer and see there are any log entries against your application or .Net Framework by any chance.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime

Comment: That's a novel one.   Microsoft programmers like using "readable" exception codes, 0x4743 spells "GC" in ascii.  So a corrupted gc heap is a pretty likely underlying cause.  Sounds like you are using .NET 4.0, be sure to let Windows Update deploy updates.  Look for unmanaged code corrupting the heap.

Comment: @M.A.Hanin i've been trying to reproduce but no success so far.

Comment: @DeepanshGupta no there is nothing on event viewer that shows any entry against my .net app.

Comment: @RichardDeeming yes im using a x64 and .NET 4.0 application.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you i will check if the pc has the updates enabled.

Comment: So i think i have found something, right before the crash i can see a msiexec(7004) Instace: The database engine stopped the instance (0). With the message below: Dirty Shutdown: 0. My application is using SQLServer 2012 to connect with can that be somehow related to the issue?