# Application crash with exit code 0xe0004743

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012-r2

My application crashed after running for some time.
I'm using .NET 4.6 on Windows Server 2012-R2.
Application is 64-bit.

I cannot find more detail about this bug code. I think I have all relevant updates installed.
This application has run cumulatively for thousands of hours before and this is the first time this particular bug happened.

Event viewer errors:

> Faulting application name:ApplicationName, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x561c9fd7
>   Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.96.0, time stamp: 0x55b96716
>   Exception code: 0xe0004743
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000003ccf84
>   Faulting process id: 0xef4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d1058c3f5834e6
>   Faulting application path: ApplicationName
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Report Id: 9765e800-7185-11e5-8177-0ae6116ba893

Second entry in the event viewer:

> Application: ApplicationName
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF837C2CF84 (00007FF837860000) with exit code **e0004743**.

The only similar issue reported in SO is [The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203751/the-process-was-terminated-due-to-an-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime) where GC issue / heap corruption was suggested.

Comment: You'll have to call Microsoft Support, they'll need the minidump.

Comment: Unfortunately minidump was not generated. Changed it now and when it happens again I'll get it and send to MS.

Comment: @Michal I know this old but do you remember how this turned out?  I'm getting the same thing and getting access to get the dump will be a pain.

Comment: @drs9222 No i don't know the root cause. I suspect some issues due to unsafe code and/or possible bugs in .NET GC