# .Net Process terminated due to .net run time error. Exit code e0004743

Tags: c#, clr, .net-runtime

We have a windows service which is actually a web server in production environment. It crashed once unexpectedly. The only clue was the event log which is as below:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          4/8/2019 6:10:10 AM
Event ID:      1023
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-6G9SE5OQD06
Description:
Application: xyz.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFFAD60B47F (00007FFFAD230000) with exit code e0004743.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1023</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-04-08T06:10:10.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>22681</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>WIN-6G9SE5OQD06</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Application: xyz.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFFAD60B47F (00007FFFAD230000) with exit code e0004743.
</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

I did reading around few articles, but dint get anything concrete information.
    One SO article is as below:
    [The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203751/the-process-was-terminated-due-to-an-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime)
But no concrete guidance. Any Help will be appreciated.

Although the process was configured to generate process dump, no process dump was generated.The following article was used to add code generated dumps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

Comment: There is not enough information to help you with this,

Comment: How long was the service running before it crashed?  Did you check the Windows Event Viewer to see if there was any error messages?

Comment: It ran for about 15 minutes and crashed. Additional hints : Its a memory intensive operation which we are performing and also there are calls to GC.Collect. Does RAM shoot up cause this issue?

Comment: I am trying to get additional error messages