# Splash screen causes a crash on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, splash-screen

I have an application written in VS2015 (FrameWork 4.0). It works fine on Windows 7, 10 but on XP SP3 it crashes.

[image]

I found that the problematic code is related to the splash screen.

Commenting out the following line does not cause the crashing anymore:

```
this.SplashScreen = new SplashScreen();
```

The entire code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices; // requires Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to be added as reference

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        new POManagementApplication().Run(args);
    }
}
class POManagementApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    #region Methods
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        this.SplashScreen = new SplashScreen();  // commenting solve the crash issue
    }
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        this.MainForm = new PrintPOForm(); 
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This is the SplashScreen Form:

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    #region Constructors
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

And the designer:

```
partial class SplashScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // SplashScreen
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackgroundImage = global::POManagement.Net.Properties.Resources.Pic1;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(839, 516);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(839, 516);
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(839, 516);
        this.Name = "SplashScreen";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Update:**

As per @Spender suggestion, following is the Application Event log:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 79480C78 (79140000)
>   with exit code 80131506.

Comment: if  you put this.SplashScreen = new SplashScreen(); in a try catch, what is the exception message ?

Comment: Are you compiling and running on the XP machine, or compiling on your non-XP development machine, copying the binaries and running on XP?

Comment: Is your XP machine 32-bit?

Comment: @GuidoG, Try..Catch.. is not helping here. it crashes with no exception thrown

Comment: @WaiHaLee, compiling on Windows 10 and running a setup prepared using InstallShield

Comment: @LordWilmore, XP is 32 bit

Comment: Are you in a situation where you can compile on the XP machine and test it?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, not I am not. VS2015 cannot be installed on XP

Comment: @ehh The Windows application event log should contain entries for the crashes. Do they contain anything more enlightening than the screenshot? .Net crashes often have a stacktrace in these entries.

Comment: @spender, updated my post following your suggestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime

Comment: @spender, thanks. It looks I do not have too much to do there. I will check it deeper.

Comment: I tried to install hotfix I got from Microsoft but it doesn't help

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is in the line 
this.BackgroundImage = global::POManagement.Net.Properties.Resources.Pic1;

check provided image is available in source or not.

Comment: no I am not using any dll. That has nothing to do with the BackgroundImage. Thanks