# How to get available job types in Quartz.Net other than manual reflection

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Currently I'm doing this the old fashioned way!

```
            var list =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                    .Where(t => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                    .ToList();
```

Is there a more "Quartz" way of doing this without manual reflection? I can't see anything about it in the docs or manually poking around namespaces.

Comment: Please, can you be more specific. Did you want all scheduled Jobs or all your Jobs that implements `IJob` or all Jobs that come along with Quartz?

Comment: Available IJob implementations that are available on the system.

Comment: Fortunately there is no Quartz way. Quartz is terrible dirty under the Hood. But to answer your question, we used a similar way to detect IJobs in our system. And i would say this way is ok. But you have to Filter all `Nullable<T>` before. If you call `typeof(Nullable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(t)`  you will run in a [Internal Error 80131506](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4367664/6666799)