# How to disable Concurrent Garbage Collector on dot net 4.5 framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to write a wpf application and in a random situation the application close with this error into event view:

> The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET
>   Runtime at IP 00007FF8E1673B60 (00007FF8E1670000) with exit code
>   80131506.

I search on google and the solution is disable Concurrent Garbage Collector, but the fix is available only for 3.5 framework and I work to 4.5 framework.

Any suggestion?
Thanks regards

Comment: check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime
There is a similar question
regards

Comment: The [`<gcConcurrent>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element).

Comment: The `<gcConcurrent/>` works in the later .NET versions too, not just 3.5. The GC name has changed from "concurrent" to "background", but it's still the same feature, and if you are getting an error actually caused by background GC, that element is what you need to disable it. Note that asking literally "how to disable concurrent GC on .NET 4.5" doesn't make any sense, because technically there is no "concurrent GC" in .NET 4.5; it's a new GC called "background GC". But the answer is still the same.

Comment: thank you @PeterDuniho may you tell me where have you read these information into msdn doc?

Comment: It's all in the link provided in the comment just before mine.

Comment: ok thankyou very much