# Application crash after update clr to 4.7

Tags: c#, .net

We have a Windows net service. It was working fine more than three years.
But two months ago, we installed a new machine and new last version of the .NET Framework (v4.7). Also we updated the .NET Framework in the service because we need new features.

After that, the service started crashing every week, once time in a week.

> Faulting application name: Service.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a2e8f7a
>   Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2053.0, time stamp: 0x58fa6d2a
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000057947
>   Faulting process id: 0x704
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d38529f1ad4283
>   Faulting application path: C:\Octopus\Applications\Service\1.0.315\Service.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Report Id: 8b138308-f165-11e7-8e89-1458d0b5ac3c
>
> Application: Service.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF9F87947 (000007FEF9F30000) with exit code 80131506.
>
> Application: Service.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF9F87947 (000007FEF9F30000) with exit code 80131506
>
> Faulting application name: Service.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a2e8f7a
>   Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2053.0, time stamp: 0x58fa6d2a
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000001bae0b
>   Faulting process id: 0xea4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d37e14ddc4b59a
>   Faulting application path: C:\Octopus\Applications\Service\1.0.315\Service.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   Report Id: 8e3458e1-ecae-11e7-8e89-1458d0b5ac3c
>
> Application: Service.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEFA0EAE0B (000007FEF9F30000) with exit code 80131506.

Do you have any clue why this can happen? In any case, I am strongly thinking about downgrading.

Comment: you would need to debug it

Comment: as a hint, look here: [Application Crashes With “Internal Error In The .NET Runtime”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime)

Comment: Thanks. I read that. But this is not ny case. We are not using cocurrent gc.

Comment: i think without seeing the lines of code where your app exactly crashs, we can only guess whats going wrong. Try to reproduce the error in debug mode and copy the code where your app stops.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall DynaTrace

Just in case you have this installed...

https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/190584/why-does-my-net-application-malfunction-after-upgr.html

https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/190584/why-does-my-net-application-malfunction-after-upgr.html

Comment: That answers.dynatrace.com link does not work anymore.