# How to fix - Application crashed with exit code 80131506

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I have a WCF application which is hosted on window service. It is frequently crashing with the below mentioned error.

Error:

Application: DataService.Server.WCF.Service.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF9131A48 (000007FEF9060000) with exit code 80131506

When the problem is checked on MSDN sites and couple of StackOverflow questions, it is understood that that it is because of concurrent garbage collection.

As per the answers for one of the question in StackOverflow, I have disabled it by setting  in the app.config file and installed the latest .NET framework version 4.7.2 in the server and even facing the error

Comment: Try force-regenerating .NET packages ([see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime/53401368#53401368)).

Comment: Hi, this is not related to the build. the service was crashing with the above error. Anyways, I have identified the issue. the issue is with the third party libraries which we are using and we have approached the relevant support team to fix the issue and share the latest binaries. the issue is now resolved